# Mahalanobis distance for outlier detection for k-Means Clustering in deployment

Tags: r, deployment

I was using Mahalanobis distance to remove outliers in the data before I used the data to do a k-Means clustering. The outliers are then a separate cluster (the "outlier" cluster), together with other clusters given by the k-Means clustering process. Now I need to deploy the modeling result in production and I'm not quite sure about how to calculate the "outlier" cluster on new data. My intuition tells me that I should not calculate the Mahalanobis distance "from scratch" on new data, but use the covariance matrix and mean from the training data, as the basic underlying assumption of machine learning is that the statistical characteristics remain the same in new data as the historical data, so if I calculate the distance from scratch, I would be treating the new data as an irrelated dataset from the training data, and it would be an inappropriate move to apply the trained clustering model, which is obtained after removing the outliers using Mahalanobis distance, in the next step to assign clusters to new observations. I'm using the `mahalanobis(x, center, cov)` function in R, so in this case, the `x` should be my new data frame, the `center` would be the means of the variables from the training data and the `cov` is the covariance matrix of the training data.

Could someone tell me if this approach is correct? If not, how should I proceed?

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems that the outliers would only go into an "outlier" cluster if they are closer to each other than they are to non-outliers. But I don't think there's any reason for outliers to be close to each other. So, it's odd to me that the approach worked in the first place to isolate outliers--although I guess this is somewhat of a tangent, since you're asking about how to use the model to classify new instances.

Comment: Maybe I didn't put it clear how the modeling process was in my post. The outliers, which were identified by the Mahalanobis distance, were not included in the clustering process (as k-Means is sensible to outliers). They are then grouped in one cluster and described as the outlier customer. And my question, in essence, is about how to appropriately identify this outlier group in the new dataset - using the statistics (covariance matrix and mean) from the historical (i.e. training) dataset or calculate the distance from scratch using the statistics of new data.